# How to merge two actions into one Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to create an application for a Report and I got stuck since getting these errors and I have no idea what to do. 
So I will try to explain what I want: one View to have two `dropdown lists` which is two different `Models`. So one `dropdown` uses `Model 1` and another `dropdown` uses `Model 2`. 
I created  two different actions for both of these two dropdowns

```
public interface IDemIzvjestaji
    {                
        public List<DvojkaVM> VratiTipove();

        public List<DvojkaVM> VratiDefinicije();
    }
```

And Implement these methods inside my `Service`

```
using IZ.BLL.Interfejsi;
using IZ.Model.DBModels;
using IZ.Model.VM;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

namespace IZ.BLL.Servisi
{
    public class DemIzvjestajiServis : IDemIzvjestaji
    {
        private AppDBContext _context;
        public DemIzvjestajiServis(AppDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public bool DemirMetodaDemo()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public List<DvojkaVM> VratiDefinicije()
        {
            var def = _context.IzvjestajDefinicija.ToList();
            if (def.Count == 0)
                return null;
            var defVM = new List<DvojkaVM>();
            foreach(var item in def)
            {
                var izvDef = new DvojkaVM();
                izvDef.text1 = item.IzvjestajDefinicijaId.ToString();
                izvDef.text2 = item.KratkiNaziv;
                defVM.Add(izvDef);
            }
            return defVM;
        }

        public List<DvojkaVM> VratiTipove()
        {
            var lista = _context.IzvjestajTip.ToList();
            if (lista.Count == 0)
                return null;
            var listaVM = new List<DvojkaVM>();
            foreach(var i in lista)
            {
                var tipVM = new DvojkaVM();
                tipVM.text1 = i.IzvjestajTipId.ToString();
                tipVM.text2 = i.Naziv;
                listaVM.Add(tipVM);
            }
            return listaVM;
        }
    }
}

And In my Controller I created Action and use ViewBag to send data to View


     public IActionResult TipIzvjestaja()
            {
                ViewBag.SelektTip = _demIzvjestajiServis.VratiTipove();
                return View("Index");
            }

            public IActionResult IzvjestajDefinicija()
            {
                ViewBag.SelektDef = _demIzvjestajiServis.VratiDefinicije();
                return View("Index");


}
```

And In View I display two dropdown lists.

```
<div>
    <p>Odaberi Tip izvještaja:</p>
    <select asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.SelektTip,"text1","text2"))" class="row form-control col-4">
        <option value="0">Odaberite</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Odaberi Definiciju Izvjestaja:</p>
    <select asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.SelektDef ,"text1","text2"))" class="row form-control col-4">
        <option value="0">Odaberite</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

After I run this I get error

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
<select asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.SelektDef ,"text1","text2"))" class="row form-control col-4">
```

I fixed this error when I split these two actions, and created another View and put DropDown List, but I want these in one View to have two `dropdown` lists.
If someone can help me, I will be very thankful.

Comment: You only need two actions if you are going to make TWO calls over HTTP... in your case you need only ONE action and add both list to the viewbag by adding both lines to the SAME action:  ViewBag.SelektTip = _demIzvjestajiServis.VratiTipove();ViewBag.SelektDef = _demIzvjestajiServis.VratiDefinicije();

Comment: Yes, but return type are not same. There are two different Tables. One dropdownlist use one table, and another one use another table

Comment: Just try what I posted in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need two actions if you are going to make TWO calls over HTTP in your case you DO NOT need two actions.

You can make it work like this:

```
        public IActionResult TipIzvjestaja()
        {
            ViewBag.SelektTip = _demIzvjestajiServis.VratiTipove();
            ViewBag.SelektDef = _demIzvjestajiServis.VratiDefinicije();
            return View("Index");
        }
```

That way you can provide your view with BOTH lists it expects.